# QEMU/libvirt: guest VM does not properly shutdown

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, qemu

Since my recent upgrade from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04, my guest VMs won't properly shutdown. Previously using ubuntu 18.04, I did not experience these problems.

I have two guest VMs - one "standard" guest operating ubuntu 18.04, and one guest with GPU-passthrough and an actual physical SSD (instead of a disk image file) operating Windows 10.

Both won't properly shutdown, when I try to shut them down from within the geust VM. My ubuntu VM initiates the shutdown - I can see the normal messages during shutdown. The last messages I see are

```
[OK] Stopped target Local File Systems (Pre).
[OK] Stopped Remount Root and Kernel File Systems.
[OK] Stopped Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[OK] Reached target Shutdown.
[OK] Reached target Final Step.
Starting Power-Off...
[44.540351] systemd-shutdown[1]: Failed to wait for process: Protocol error
```

Then the guest VM stays stuck like that and the status in my virtual machine manager says "Shutting Down"

If I try to force a shutdown using the `virsh destroy`command, I get the errors

```
error: Failed to destroy domain ubuntu18.04
error: Failed to terminate process 4736 with SIGTERM: permission denied
```

Something similar happens with my Windows VM. Windows starts the shut down, the screen connected to the passed-through GPU goes black and I am back in my host system. However, the status in my virtual machine manager is stuck in "shutting down".

During the upgrade of my host system from ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 I was asked if I wanted to replace some config files or keep my old config files, which I have manually adjusted. I remember that I kept old config files if I have manually adjusted them because I did not want to lose my custom settings/configs. Keeping old config files already caused me running into https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1833040 which I solved by manually editing the one line in the apparmor abstraction file as described in the bug fix.

Therefore, I suspect that some old config files from ubuntu 18.04 which I did not update during the upgrade are causing my problems. Do you agree with this, or is something else more likely? If the old config files are the most probably cause, how do I get the new updated ubuntu 20.04 config files?

Comment: I agree that there are apparmor rules for the signals that need to be sent on shutdown. I'd recommend comparing your custom conffiles with the ones you'd get out of a new package of the version that you manually modified them. Then upgrade to the apparmor rules of the new package and - if still needed - add back the few rules you added.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This may sound stupid, but how exactly to I reset the apparmor rules? Do I have to completely `apt-get purge apparmor` and then install it again, or is there a better, "less invasive" solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Christian Ehrhardt, apparmor was indeed the culprit. I noticed, that the new default abstraction for libvirt-qemu was saved in `/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu.dpkg-dist` during the upgrade process, so I could merge the changes in the new default abstraction with my custom modifications without having to re-install apparmor.

Now my VMs are shutting down fine again.

Comment: MisterX, could you please elaborate a bit more on exactly what you did? I have the same problem and wondering if it could be apparmor as well. Host is running latest version of Debian (12) with Client being Ubuntu on desktop version (22.04). And Ubuntu (as you had described) is stuck on it's shutdown screen. Otherwise it is running fine. I had a look in apparmor as per debian (/etc/apparmor.d/abstractions/libvirt-qemu/) but am not certain as to what to edit. Thank you